# Retrieve SharePoint 2013 site collection information using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, csom

I have been trying to retrieve SharePoint site collection inside a different ASP.NET web application using CSOM as follows.

```
using (var context = new ClientContext("https://sharePointSite/"))
            {
                var credentials= new NetworkCredential("userName", "password", "domain");
                context.Credentials = credentials;
                context.Load(context.Web, w => w.Title);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

}
```

Above code work as expected when I am running it locally (dev environment), but I get following error message when publish to the web server.

> The remote server returned an error: (501) Not Implemented.

Web application using .NET Framework 4.5.2, Visual Studio 2015. Web server is different from SharePoint server.

Does anyone had issue like this?

Comment: Is your web server behind a proxy? Might need to configure the proxy settings in your web app.